# convert numpy array to integer array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have array

```
length = 7
angle = 30  
x = [1.21660254e+02, 1.71660254e+02, 2.38660254e+02, 2.05660254e+02]
```

I tried this

```
P2x =  int(np.round(x + length * math.cos(math.radians(-angle))))
```

gives me error `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Comment: ```P2x = int(...)``` You're casting it to an int, which is a scalar

Comment: I want integer values

Comment: Use ```new_array = your_array.astype(np.int)```

Comment: Please clearly define what you want. Do you want a numpy array of integers, an array.array of integers, or a list of integers?

Comment: `int` (and `math.cos()`) only works for **one** number at a time, not an array of numbers.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I tried astype(np.int) still gives same error

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I want numpy array of integers

Comment: @hpaulj So what would work for array of numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `math` module if you are already using `numpy`

```
import numpy as np

length = 7
angle = 30 
x = [1.21660254e+02, 1.71660254e+02, 2.38660254e+02, 2.05660254e+02]

xP2x = np.round(np.array(x) + length * np.cos(np.radians(-angle))).astype(int)
print(xP2x)
```

Out:

```
[128 178 245 212]
```